# Юго-Западная Таврика как пишется?

Tags: прописная-строчная

Юго-Западная Таврика как пишется? Все слова с прописных?

Answer (score 2):

Все три слова с прописной - это имена собственные.

[Юго-Западная Таврика — распространённое в научной исторической литературе название для части Крыма, принадлежащих бассейну рек Чёрная, Бельбек, Кача и Альма. Так как Таврика в узком смысле — это горный Крым (а не весь полуостров), то западная часть Горного Крыма с выходом к морю между Чёрной и Альмой, может также называться Западной Таврикой.](http://krymology.info/index.php/%D0%AE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)

---

> Состав населения Юго-Западной Таврики отличался нестабильностью,
> взаимодействовавшие здесь этносы представляли собой различные по
> социально-политической организации и экономическому базису сообщества,
> в одинаковой мере не являвшиеся носителями сложившейся городской
> культуры.